# Catkin-compiled Code Runs 3x slower

Tags: navigation, catkin, costmap, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been running a slate of tests on the new hydro navigation. I was trying to figure out why updating the costmap in the new hydro version takes so much longer than in the old 'Fuerte' version. (Note that both of these are tested in Groovy)

I searched and searched to figure out how the new code was different. But it wasn't the code at all. It was the compiler.

[image: graph of runtimes]

The colors of each segment of the bar are irrelevant in this case. The first row shows how long the catkin-compiled version of the Hydro code takes to update the costmap once. The second bar shows the same operation in Fuerte, which is compiled using Rosbuild. The third is the same exact code from the first bar, but compiled using Rosbuild.

My question is: what accounts for this 3x slowdown when compiling with Catkin?

Links:

- [Catkin CMake](https://github.com/DLu/navigation/blob/groovy_stable/costmap_2d/CMakeLists.txt)
- [Rosbuild CMake](http://pastebin.com/2rEPY7r5)
- [Other](https://i.imgur.com/pnoL6zi.jpg)

Edit: The benchmark was performed using locally compiled packages and the timing was measured with repeated gettimeofday calls (since that infrastructure was already in the code for measuring update-time.)

Edit 2: Thanks to William's comment, I figured it out.
[image: another chart]

Explanation: The update loop timing is usually only available in the ROS_DEBUG information. Printing the DEBUG logs takes a bit of time, which you can see with the red bars. For the packages I compiled, I also changed it to be printed quicker without ROS_DEBUG. However, I couldn't do that for the debian package.

The key result is that Rosbuild code (which William mentions, already was built in Release mode) runs as fast as the catkin code with the release flag set.

I don't know why the Debian is as slow as it is, but its not going to bother me immediately.

(@William: Put your answer below for some sweet sweet karma)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/71965/catkin-compiled-code-runs-3x-slower/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2013-08-09

Post score: 13

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-08-09**:
Can you describe how you did the benchmark? Did you compiled the packages locally from source? Did you used the available Debian packages?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-08-09**:
Can you please post a comparison between the locally self-built package in Hydro vs. the publically available Debian package?

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2013-08-09**:
Working on the tests, but a quick note: The set(ROS_BUILD_TYPE Release) line isn't mine. It's Eitan's from 2009. https://github.com/DLu/navigation/commit/fa4430e4780453d69150d8a8b40d7f427970950f

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-08-09**:
@David Lu, sure it is actually part of the default rosbuild CMakeLists.txt template.

**Comment by [mateus03](https://answers.ros.org/users/18781/mateus03/) on 2014-07-18**:
When I install ros hydro on my pc, it already comes with the navigation stack. Is the code compiled with catkin without the flag set to Release? How can I compile it with the flag?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-07-19**:
Yes - all packages built on the build farm are compiled in release mode.

**Comment by [mateus03](https://answers.ros.org/users/18781/mateus03/) on 2014-07-20**:
Ok, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just to reiterate, be mindful of the ROS_BUILD_TYPE, whether set by default in your CMake or invoked on the command line. Compiling with

```
catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

will ensure that your Catkin code is as fast as possible.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2013-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 11

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-08-09**:
Just for the record these are the default build flags with CMake and if not defined CMake will use "none":

```
None: *no flags*
Debug: -g
Release: -O3 -DNDEBUG
RelWithDebInfo: -O2 -g
MinSizeRel: -Os -DNDEBUG
```

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2013-08-11**:
As a side note, do you realize how low the probability of me memorizing that exact flag configuration is? For such an important functionality, it seems like a relatively arcane incantation.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-08-11**:
That is why CMake uses reasonable default flags for the different build types. And catkin_make provides completion on arguments like "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE" since they are not that memorable.

**Comment by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on 2013-10-13**:
It works! It took me a week to figure this out. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In your rosbuild CMake you do `set(ROS_BUILD_TYPE Release)`, the equivalent variable in CMake is `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`, but it is not good form to put that into the CMakeLists.txt directly because then it cannot be overridden externally. Try the timing tests with `catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release`.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-08-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Greydon](https://answers.ros.org/users/31612/greydon/) on 2017-08-17**:
I realize this is a very old thread, but if you do want to specify a default CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE flag in your CMakeLists.txt, you can do it safely with

```
if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE) 
    set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
endif(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
```